# Email regex validation javascript should not contain example.com

Tags: javascript, regex, email

I have requirement for email validation that the email should not be with a particular domain,

for example if the email is `email@example.com` it is invalid. That is the `RegExp` should exclude the domain example.com

I tried to use like to exclude a string like

```
^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$.?!example.com
```

It's not working

Please help me with a `RegExp`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex

```
(?=.*@)(?!.*example).*
```

This matches, all emails, that does not come from domain `example.com`

I've made a function for you.

```
function isValidEmail(input, excludedDomain) {
    alert(new RegExp("(?=.*@)(?!.*" + excludedDomain + ").*").test(input));
}
isValidEmail("hi@example.com", "example"); //false
isValidEmail("hi@hotmail.com", "example"); //true
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/W3rLU/

Answer (score 1):

The correct Regexp is something like this.

```
^\w+@(?!example\.com)[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/7BEeIbowUhNir6Lx)

It means: after the @, check that is not followed by "example.com" and then check that is followed by a character and a two or three letter domain.

I also recommend you to change it a bit to allow domain names with numbers and dashes (e.g. `myname@domain-123.com`) and subdomains (`myname@subdomain.domain.com`) with this expression:

```
^\w+@(?!example\.com)[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,6})$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/95O1alcBaPU8Y3pr)